# How to unmarshal embedded structs from yaml

Tags: go, yaml, unmarshalling

I would like to unmarshal yaml using embedded structs mostly for DRY:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

type Employee struct {
    Person
    Number string
}

func (c *Employee) Dump() {
    d, err := yaml.Marshal(c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- dump:\n%s\n\n", string(d))
}

func main() {
    s := `
name: john
number: one
`

    c := &Employee{}
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(s), c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
    }

    c.Dump()
}
```

This results in:

```
--- dump:
person:
  name: ""
number: one
```

How can the embedded Person be unmarshaled?

Comment: Does adding a `\`yaml:",inline"\`` tag to the `Person` field in the `Employee` struct declaration helps?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should add the inline tag, as example:

```
type Employee struct {
    Person `yaml:",inline"`
    Number string
}
```

This will output:

```
--- dump:
name: john
number: one
```

[Here](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/63) a discussion about it

Hope this help